# Pass the data to errors custom page on laravel

Tags: laravel

I did create a custom 404 page on my Laravel project by creating a folder called `errors` and inside the folder I did create a file called `404.blade.php`

However when I use a component and I try to pass the data with that component I get an error

```
<x-main-header-component></x-main-header-component>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Main Header -->

<x-main-navbar-component></x-main-navbar-component>


<!-- ... end User Menu Popup -->


error message here 

<x-main-footer-component :message="$SocialMediaLinks"></x-main-footer-component>




</body>
</html>
```

the error that I'm getting is:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable $SocialMediaLinks (View:
```

What can I do to pass the data to the component `main-footer` on `errors/404.blade.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one ways you can achieve this. Since we have no access to `404Controller` or anything like so, I usually come up with several ideas:

1. **Directly import** the targetted data source (model for example). This will guarantee result, but the view may look ugly and not that logical.
2. **Caching**: Redis, Memcache or anything will help. If your error views are using the same data source as your landing pages (navigation bar, header for example). The idea is that you will use `Cache::remember()` to store and get data whereever you want. [Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#retrieve-store)
3. **View composer**: ([Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers)). Cleanest way in my opinion. You just share data to all views (error views included) using global `*` regular expression.
4. **Use helper**: Since helpers are globally available, you can use it to store and retrieve data as you want.

For JavaScript framework component availability, just include it (the `.js` file) in the error views under `resources/views/errors`.

---

Example for the 3rd method:

In your `AppServiceProvider@boot`:

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with([
        'somethingToShare' => "Hello world",
    ]);
});
```

In your error views:

```
{{dd($somethingToShare)}}
```

Now when you open your targetted error view, it should show "Hello World"

Comment: can you post a code example for the 3rd one View composer?

Comment: @Buildermine I added an example for illustration. Leave a comment if it worked for you.

Comment: yep, that was great i just refactored my code and made it less, thanks man for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are calling $SocialMediaLinks in your app or footer.
if you are, then use an helper function. i'll add my example below

```
 @if (isset($seo))

    <title>{{ $seo->title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $seo->meta_description }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ $seo->meta_keywords }}">
@else

    @php
        $seo = getSEO();  //helper function
    @endphp

    <title>{{ $seo->title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $seo->meta_description }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ $seo->meta_keywords }}">
@endif
```